# My Program Is Trapped In A Weird Freeze/Infinite Loop

Tags: vb.net, freeze, sudoku

I am writing a Sudoku App In VB.NET. Currently I am working on the implementation for a Sudoku puzzle generator. The one I have written is having a weird issue where the application just comes to a standstill. At first I just rationally assumed that I had an infinite loop somewhere in my code. So I added a feature where the function would reset if the do...while loop ran more than 50 times in a row. But that didn't do anything! For the life of me I **cannot** figure out what is going on with my program. If anyone can explain this freeze, I would be *so* grateful.

Here is my Function/Sub/Sub-procedure:

```
Private Sub CreatePuzzle(ByVal Dificulty As Integer)
    Dim Rand As New Random()
    For Each Row As List(Of Box) In Rows
        Dim UsedNumbers As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim Column As Integer = 0
        For Each Cell As Box In Row
            Column = Cell.Column
            Dim I As Integer
            Do
                I = Math.Floor(Rand.NextDouble() * 9) + 1
            Loop While Arrays.Contains(UsedNumbers.ToArray(), I) Or _
                       Arrays.Contains(Box.GetValues(Columns(Column)), I) Or _
                       Arrays.Contains(Box.GetValues(Squares(Math.Floor(Column / 3D))), I)
            Cell.Val(I)
            UsedNumbers.Add(I)
            Debug.Print("Row: " & "ABCDEFGHI"(Cell.Row) & ", Column: " & _
                (Cell.Column + 1).ToString() & ", Square: " & Cell.Square.ToString() & _
                ", (Predicted) Square: " & Math.Floor(Column / 3D).ToString())
            Debug.Print("I: " & I.ToString())
            Debug.Print("")
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Also, Here is the implementation for the custom `Box` class I use to represent the cells in the Sudoku puzzle:

```
Public Class Box
Private _Value As Integer = 0
Private _Row As Integer
Private _Column As Integer
Private _Square As Integer
Private Label As Label
Private _Name As String

Public ReadOnly Property Value As Integer
    Get
        Return _Value
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Row As Integer
    Get
        Return _Row
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Column As Integer
    Get
        Return _Column
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Square As Integer
    Get
        Return _Square
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
    Get
        Return Label.Name
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub New(ByRef Box As Label)
    Dim Values As String() = Box.Tag.ToString.Split(",")
    If Not Box.Text = "" Then
        _Value = Integer.Parse(Box.Text)
    End If
    _Row = Integer.Parse(Values(0))
    _Column = Integer.Parse(Values(1))
    _Square = Integer.Parse(Values(2))
    Label = Box
End Sub

Public Sub Val(ByVal Digit As Char, ByRef PreVal As Integer, ByRef PrevSelect As Label)
    Dim Value As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(Digit, Value) AndAlso Not Value = 0 Then
        If Label.Text = "" Then
            PreVal = 0
        Else
            PreVal = Integer.Parse(PrevSelect.Text)
        End If
        PrevSelect = Label
        Label.Text = Digit
        _Value = Value
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Val(ByVal Digit As Integer)
    If Digit = 0 Then
        Label.Text = ""
    Else
        Label.Text = Digit.ToString()
    End If
    _Value = Digit
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetValues(ByVal Boxes As List(Of Box)) As Integer()
    Dim Output(Boxes.Count - 1) As Integer
    For I As Integer = 0 To Output.GetUpperBound(0)
        Output(I) = Boxes(I).Value
    Next
    Return Output
End Function
End Class
```

EDIT: Here is the code for Arrays.Contains()

```
Function Contains(ByVal HayStack() As Integer, ByVal Needle As Integer) As Boolean
    For I As Integer = 0 To HayStack.GetUpperBound(0)
        If HayStack(I) = Needle Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Please write a comment if there is any custom implementation you need to see not already here.

Comment: Which is the infinite loop? Have you debugged to see where your code loops infinitely?

Comment: @Josh Part The Do... While loop in CreatePuzzle()

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question? If someone explained to me why they downvoted the question I would be happy to address it.

Comment: Note that your loop loops **while** the condition holds, not **until**.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I want it to loop "while" the condition holds. Its supposed to generate a number **not** in already in the array.

Comment: You really should debug your program. I.e. set a break point, single-step through it and look what happens.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I did, and it seems to be consistently stopping at the 3rd iteration of the outer foreach loop, and the 1st iteration of the inner for each loop.

Comment: You can also inspect the variables and add expressions or parts of expressions to the Quick Watch window. If you do so, you will see why the loop condition remains true.

Comment: @Null It looks like it's trying to find a value of 1 through 9 in 3 separate arrays.  Once all 9 values can be found in any array, wont it be stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: There are several basic NET methods which if used, you could get rid of most of that code.

Comment: @JimHewitt I think I found the problem. The math being done in the `Squares()` indexer is inaccurate because it is not at all dependent on the row. Thus meaning that as soon as it gets to row #4, it is looking at the first square again, and of course it is filled up.

Comment: at it to another thread you can at least interact with your program while its completing its task.

Answer (score 0):

OK... So it turns out that it wasn't an infinite loop, but such an inefficient algorithm that it took 10 min to create the puzzle.

Comment: see my answer for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

My crude attempt at creating a Sudoku puzzle.  To use the class.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim foo As New Puzzle()
    RichTextBox1.Text = foo.Display
    RichTextBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

The class

```
Public Class Puzzle
    Private Shared PRNG As New Random
    Private _thePuzzle As New List(Of List(Of Integer))
    Public thePuzzle As New List(Of List(Of Integer))

    Private base As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).OrderBy(Function(x) PRNG.Next).ToList
    Public Sub New(Optional empties As Integer = 27)
        'creat base puzzle
        For x As Integer = 0 To 2 'first three rows
            Me._thePuzzle.Add(New List(Of Integer))
            Me.thePuzzle.Add(New List(Of Integer))
            Me._thePuzzle(x).AddRange(base)
            'blocks of three from front to rear
            base.AddRange(base.GetRange(0, 3))
            base.RemoveRange(0, 3)
        Next

        'DebugHelp(Me._thePuzzle)

        For x As Integer = 0 To 5 'next six rows
            base.Clear()
            base.AddRange(Me._thePuzzle(x))
            base.Add(base(0))
            base.RemoveAt(0)
            Me._thePuzzle.Add(New List(Of Integer))
            Me.thePuzzle.Add(New List(Of Integer))
            Me._thePuzzle(Me._thePuzzle.Count - 1).AddRange(base)
        Next

        'DebugHelp(Me._thePuzzle)

        '' shuffle
        Const shuffles As Integer = 3

        For sh As Integer = 1 To shuffles
            Me.Shuffle()
        Next

        'visible
        For r As Integer = 0 To Me._thePuzzle.Count - 1
            Me.thePuzzle(r).AddRange(Me._thePuzzle(r))
        Next

        DebugHelp(Me.thePuzzle)
        'set certain entries to zero
        Dim idxs As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, 81).ToList
        For x As Integer = 1 To empties
            Dim rmx As Integer = PRNG.Next(idxs.Count)
            Dim idx As Integer = idxs(rmx)
            idxs.RemoveAt(rmx)
            Dim r As Integer
            Dim c As Integer
            r = Math.DivRem(idx, 9, c)
            Me.thePuzzle(r)(c) = 0
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(0)
        Next

        ' DebugHelp(Me.thePuzzle)
    End Sub

    Public Function Display() As String
        Dim rv As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim fmt As String = "{0,3}"
        For r As Integer = 0 To 8
            For c As Integer = 0 To 8
                If Me.thePuzzle(r)(c) = 0 Then
                    rv.AppendFormat(fmt, "□")
                Else
                    rv.AppendFormat(fmt, Me.thePuzzle(r)(c))
                End If
                If c Mod 3 = 2 AndAlso c <> 8 Then rv.AppendFormat(fmt, "|")
            Next
            rv.AppendLine()
            If r Mod 3 = 2 AndAlso r <> 8 Then
                rv.AppendLine("---------------------------------")
                'rv.AppendLine("_________________________________")
            End If
        Next
        Return rv.ToString
    End Function

    Private Sub Shuffle()
        Dim temp As Integer
        Dim agrp As Integer
        Dim IDT As Integer
        Dim IDF As Integer

        agrp = PRNG.Next(Me._thePuzzle.Count \ 3) * 3
        Do
            IDT = PRNG.Next(3) + agrp
            IDF = PRNG.Next(3) + agrp
        Loop While IDT = IDF

        'swap rows
        base.Clear()
        base.AddRange(Me._thePuzzle(IDT))
        Me._thePuzzle(IDT).Clear()
        Me._thePuzzle(IDT).AddRange(Me._thePuzzle(IDF))
        Me._thePuzzle(IDF).Clear()
        Me._thePuzzle(IDF).AddRange(base)

        'swap columns
        For rw As Integer = 0 To Me._thePuzzle.Count - 1
            temp = Me._thePuzzle(rw)(IDF)
            Me._thePuzzle(rw)(IDF) = Me._thePuzzle(rw)(IDT)
            Me._thePuzzle(rw)(IDT) = temp
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub DebugHelp(sl As List(Of List(Of Integer)))
        Debug.WriteLine("")
        For r As Integer = 0 To sl.Count - 1
            Debug.Write("'")
            For c As Integer = 0 To sl(r).Count - 1
                Debug.Write(sl(r)(c) & " ")
            Next
            Debug.WriteLine("")
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```